# Dot pipeline data with constant matrix

Tags: python, keras, matrix-multiplication, keras-layer

Is it possible to multiply the batch in the middle of the pipeline with a constant transformation? Something along the lines of

```
constant_non_trainable_matrix = numpy.array([...]) # shape (n,n)

input = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(shape = (n,))
dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense((n,))(input)
transform = MultiplyWithMatrix(constant_non_trainable_matrix)(dense_1)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense((n,))(transform)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = input, outputs = output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Lambda` layer and `backend.dot()` to achieve that:

```
from keras import layers
from keras import backend as K

# ...
transformed = layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.dot(x, mat))(dense_1)
```

You need to construct the `mat` tensor using the backend functions as well (e.g. `K.constant()`, `K.variable()`, etc.).

Comment: That looks much cleaner than the solution I just found (using `Dense(out_dim,trainable=False,use_bias=False,weights=[mat])(dense_1)`), thank you :)